# Tkinter Text widget : Fetching Cursor Selection

Tags: python, text, indexing, tkinter, cursor

I have a text widget, and I have the text

```
this is some random text
```

With the keyboard cursor in the word "`random`". How can I get the start and end index of the cursor selection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of the start of the word by applying the modifier `"wordstart"` to an index. To get the end of the word, use `"wordend"`.

For example:

```
start = text.index("insert wordstart")
end = text.index("insert wordend")
```

Comment: would selection (SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST) not be appropriate in this scenario?

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that

Comment: @0x52-0x75-0x63-0x79: no, because the question says nothing about the selection.